# Array element not being assigned in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get an a value of id assigned to an array element. The problem I am having is that it will assign one id every 70 loops through the foreach. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong on this one.

```
$search = 'echem';
$data = array();
$tags = null;
$i = 0;
//var_dump($this->videos);
foreach ($this->videos as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'id') {
            $data[$i]['id'] = (int)$value;
        }
        if ($key == 'tags') {
            $tags = explode(',', $value);
        }
        //echo $key . ' - ';
        if (is_array($tags)) {
            foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
                if (strtoupper($value) == strtoupper($search)) {
                    //echo 'Search Found <br/>';
                    $data[$i]['found'] = 1;
                }
                //echo $value.', ';
            }
            //echo '<br/>';
        }
        if (!isset($data[$i]['found'])) {
            $data[$i]['found'] = 0;
        }
        $data[$i]['subId'] = $i;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

as you can see im checking to see if the $key is id on line 8 with the following code:

```
if ($key === 'id') {
     $data[$i]['id'] = (int)$value;
}
```

I then run through the rest of the loop which appears to run through just fine and assign everything as needed. The key id is the first key in every loop through so why its not assigning it has me stumped. Any help is much appreciated.

output of var_dump():

```
array (size=58086)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'found' => int 0
      'subId' => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'found' => int 0
      'subId' => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'found' => int 0
      'subId' => int 2
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'found' => int 0
      'subId' => int 3
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'found' => int 0
      'subId' => int 4
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'found' => int 1
      'subId' => int 5
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'found' => int 0
      'subId' => int 6
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'found' => int 0
      'subId' => int 7
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($data)` produce after the `foreach`?

Comment: It won't cause an issue in this context, but you shouldn't overwrite `$value` in the nested `foreach` loops.

Comment: All three of your foreach loops both use `$key => $value` - that's a little confusing to follow. You should give them different names, to make maintaining your code easier.

Comment: @andrewsi: and that's the whole bug too - the inner loops are overwriting the $key values for the outer loops.

Comment: `foreach ($value as $key => $value) {` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: added a sample of the var_dump(). changed the names for all of the $key => $value elements to differ and be more descriptive. That var_dump is after the change in naming which still produces the same result.

Comment: You definitively should change each `$key => $value` and give their own variable names, that will likely fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was a bit bored, so I rewrote your code:

1. I've renamed the `as $key => $value` to more sensible names.
2. I've removed the middle `foreach` loop, because a simple array reference and `isset()` suffices.
3. Applying `strtoupper()` to `$search` before the loop starts (avoids having to do this multiple times).

Result:

```
$search = 'echem';
$data = array();

$i = 0;
$search = strtoupper($search);

foreach ($this->videos as $video) {
    if (!isset($video['id'], $video['tags'])) {
        continue; // skip records you can't use
    }
    // populate the `$data` entry
    $data[$i]['id'] = $video['id'];
    $data[$i]['tags'] = explode(',', $video['tags']);

    // find a match in the tags
    $data[$i]['found'] = 0;
    foreach ($data[$i]['tags'] as $tag) {
        if (strtoupper($tag) == $search) {
            $data[$i]['found'] = 1;
        }
    }
    $data[$i]['subId'] = $i;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You forgot `$i = 0;` before the loop starts :)